# nodejs express profile property in request

Tags: node.js, express

I got very confused for one usage:

In the route file:

```
  app.param('userId', users.load);
```

And the users.load function:

```
exports.load = function (req, res, next, id) {
    var options = {
        criteria: { _id : id }
    };
    User.load(options, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) return next(new Error('Failed to load User ' + id));
        req.profile = user;
        next();
    });
};
```

Here, route should have the userId to response but why does the author use `req.profile` here. `profile` is not a property.

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the code does is this: for routes that have a `userId` parameter (that is, routes that look similar to this: `/user/:userId`), Express will call the `load()` function *before* the route handler is called.

The load function loads the user profile belonging to the userId from the database, and adds it to `req` as a newly created property `req.profile`.

The `.profile` property name is arbitrarily named by the author and demonstrates the fact that it's perfectly valid to add properties to `req` (or `res`, for that matter, but convention is to add these properties to `req`).

In the route handler, you can then use `req.profile`. It's basically a way of propagating data from middleware and `app.param()` implementations to other parts of the route handling.

Answer (score 0):

the line req.profile = users; think of it this way, 'i want to take all the powers of the users and paste them to req.profile' why? remember this part is sort of a middleware if you want to target any of the read, update and delete code it has to pass through here, it only makes sense if it involves the req, because you are practically requesting to access the said pages (read, edit and delete or any other:userId page) now the profile name doesn't matter you could use any name but its sort of a convention in the community to use the profile name.